# Copy data of mp3 file to another file. C

Tags: c, file, copy, mp3

I try to copy data from mp3 file to another file.

But all the charter that I get from the file is '-1' ASCCI.

I open scannedFile by "rb" mode.

This is the code:

```
// scannedFile = music.mp3, lastByte = 1000, firstByte = 3
char* data = calloc(lastByte - firstByte + 2, sizeof(char));
for (i = 0; i <= lastByte - firstByte; i++)
{
    c = fgetc(scannedFile);
    if (c == 0) // if the char is 0 ( END OF STRING ) change it for another charter.
        c = 1;
    data[i] = c;
}
```

Comment: mp3 file are binary and will contain non-ascii character and won't be null terminated.  Your code is expecting text files and will corrupt binary files.

Comment: @antlersoft Hey, but I open the 'scannedFILE' by "rb" mode.
it's also not working..

Comment: The MP3 file is not a string, so 0 bytes are completely irrelevant and don't mark the end of it.

Comment: the source of the problem is not in the code you posted.  Suggest posting how the file name was setup and the fopen() statement AND follow the fopen() statement with: `if( NULL = scannedFile) { perror( "fopen failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`  as that will output (on stderr) the reason the OS thinks the fopen() failed

Comment: the code is missing the declaration of `c`, which has to be: `int c;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here: [fgetc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgetc/)

It says that the return can be either the current char or [EOF](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/EOF/)  which is literally -1:

> On success, the character read is returned (promoted to an int value).
>   The return type is int to accommodate for the special value EOF, which indicates failure:
>   If the position indicator was at the end-of-file, the function returns EOF and sets the eof indicator (feof) of stream.
>   If some other reading error happens, the function also returns EOF, but sets its error indicator (ferror) instead.

So you should look into the EOF indicator of the stream as well as the error indicator (ferror) for the answer.

Comment: Ok, So you have idea what i need to do for read the data of mp3 file ?

Comment: @YairB. To get the idea I would need to know what's up with the file handle you try to use.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I fix my problem, i was problem in fseek.
Thank for all for try to help :)

Comment: So you simply was hitting the EOF...as I said.

Comment: @ZverevEugene yes, how i mark the question is solved ?

Comment: Accept the answer that you posted.  I think there is some minimum time between when you post an answer and when you can accept it. (IIRC: 9 minutes)